# Excel formula / AWK equivalent

Tags: excel, bash, awk

I'm trying to automate many calculations from several files. I've done it with Excel and have the formulas needed.

My input `Input.txt` is

```
Start   End
0   0
1793    3233
3147    4045
4085    6751
28077   29336
29258   31431
29304   30010
31528   42846
```

What I'm trying to get is the `Size` from `Start` to `End` and substract the possible overlaps: e.g. in row 4, the `Start` (3147) overlaps with the `End` of row 3 (3233), so the effective `Size` is only 813, due to that overlap.

Row 8 in this example (29304 - 30010) is not only overlapped but is contained by row 7 (29258 - 31431) so it doesn't add any effective size.

My desired output `Out.txt` is:

```
Start   End Size    No-Negatives    Overlap No-Negatives
0   0   0   0   0   0
1793    3233    1442    1442    -1792   0
3147    4045    813 813 87  87
4085    6751    2668    2668    -39 0
28077   29336   1261    1261    -21325  0
29258   31431   2096    2096    79  79
29304   30010   -1420   0   2128    2128
31528   42846   11320   11320   -96 0
```

The final number I need, which I can easily calculate once I have the complete table is the sum of `$4` which tells me the effective total size.

I've done it in Excel adding the original `Input.txt` to columns A and B and used the next formulas to obtain columns `$3` to `$6` of `Out.txt` (Size, No-negatives, Overlap, No-negatives)

`$3` (C): `=B3-(A3+F3)+2`

`$4` (D): `=IF(C3>0,C3,0)`

`$5` (E): `=B2-A3+1`

`$6` (F): `=IF(E3>0,E3,0)`

Is there a `bash`, `awk`, or any script with which I can obtain columns `` to process many files?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$1` contains the first field, `$2` the second and so on. Values will be interpreted as integers if you do arithmetic on them. I don't get the output requested though and how it should be presented. Please explain, or even better, show us.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: Original imput is only columns $1 (A) and $2 (B). The desired output is the complete File.xls I show above with columns $1 to $6 (A to F) given those calculations for each column.

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the required output, using the nice formatting tools at the top left of the text input box, especially the `{}` tool. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following script.

Content of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN { 
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}

FNR >= 3 { 
    $5 = L2 - $1 + 1 
    $6 = $5 > 0 ? $5 : 0 
    $3 = $2 - ($1 + $6) + 2 
    $4 = $3 > 0 ? $3 : 0 
    print $0
}

{
    L2 = $2
}

FNR < 3 { 
    print
    next
}
```

Assuming following content of `infile`:

```
S Scer  E Scer
0   0
1793    3233
3147    4045
4085    6751
28077   29336
29258   31431
29304   30010
31528   42846
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

That yields:

```
S Scer  E Scer
0   0 
1793 3233 1442 1442 -1792 0
3147 4045 813 813 87 87
4085 6751 2668 2668 -39 0
28077 29336 1261 1261 -21325 0
29258 31431 2096 2096 79 79
29304 30010 -1420 0 2128 2128
31528 42846 11320 11320 -1517 0
```

Put the headers as you want is left as work for you.

Comment: You did it! I actually edited the question while you gave me the right script!